# No templates available when creating a new project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, templates, projects-and-solutions

*"No template information found. See the application log in Event Viewer for more details. To open Event Viewer, click Start, click Control Panel, double-click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Event Viewer."*

That's the error message I get when I try to create a new project or solution.
How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used a solution presented to me from other sites. One of them said to reinstall templates.
I did the following:

In the command prompt I typed: cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE

Then I typed: devenv /installvstemplates

I took a minute but after it completed I opened Visual Studio and tried to create a new project. All my project templates were back in order, including additional templates like Workflow, SharePoint and Silverlight.

[Link to other source](http://blog-mstechnology.blogspot.com/2009/08/no-template-information-found-visual.html)

Comment: This also applies to express versions of visual studio

Comment: For VS2013 use this path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE

Comment: For VS2013 as thd above said use this path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE and I had to use devenv.exe /installvstemplates instead of devenv /installvstemplates

Comment: Yes it did work for me @r.hamd I tried it with just devenv /installvstemplates and nothing happened but devenv.exe did the trick but I am not sure why

Comment: @vbp lucky you, i tried every possibility and it did not work for me, untill i repaired which took me more than two hours

Answer (score 8):

Start Menu --> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 --> Visual Studio Tools. **Right-click over the Visual Studio Command Prompt shortcut and make sure you select Run as Administrator.** Once the VS Command Prompt comes up, execute the command without Quot,

1. "devenv /installvstemplates"
2. "devenv /resetsettings"

   And that worked out.

Comment: @AlexanderN i have the same problem with vs2013 but this solution did not work

Answer (score 1):

Run Following command and it will restore templates.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE>devenv /installvstemplates

Answer (score 0):

This may not match the original posters exact symptoms but I was seeing a blank screen after clicking **Create a new project** (VS 2019). Discovered that the install of Visual Studio had 'finished with errors' (paraphrasing there - now I've fixed the issue I can't see the exact error message) anyhow digging into it I found that the C++ redistributable had not installed (even though I'm a C# dev that's still important to VS!)

If I tried to install this as a standalone I got an **Access Denied** error (even if running as Administrator). Digging into the VS install logs I found a similar report.

Anyhow after a fair amount of Googling a few responses pointed to Virus software preventing the C++ redistributable from installing (in my case McAfee). Once that was removed a repair of VS resolved the issue :)