# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: val In VS Monogame project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, monogame

I'm trying to edit the properties tab of my MonoGame but when I try to it comes up with

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: val

I'm pretty new to this and I'm not sure what is causing this? Everything works as intended and I'm not getting any runtime errors.

Here is my code:

This is Game1.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace HorrorgameMono
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D PlayerRightWalk;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            PlayerRightWalk = Content.Load<Texture2D>("PlayerAnimations/playerWalkingRight");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            // Allows the game to exit
            KeyboardState state = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            {
                this.Exit();
            }

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(PlayerRightWalk, new Rectangle(100, 100, 128, 32), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is Program.cs

```cs
using System;


namespace HorrorgameMono
{
#if WINDOWS || LINUX
    /// <summary>
    /// The main class.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var game = new Game1())
                game.Run();
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

The project runs fine on its own, it just doesn't let me edit the properties.

Comment: The `visual-studio` tag should only be used for questions about Visual Studio.

Comment: This is a problem in vs?

Comment: where is your `val` parameter, code?!

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi where could i find that?

Comment: In one of your method, you have a parameter with the name of `val`. isn't it in `Game` class ?

Comment: cant see val anywhere in game1 i even searched it, i also cant open properties on any project even new ones ive created

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure what was wrong, so i re-installed visual studio and now the properties show up!

Comment: I had the same error, although in my case it was on a new machine & fresh install a bit different to what you saw as I had no files showing - turned out VS hadn't installed correctly - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61098640/4925121